# Client.event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro' with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to create a Discord Bot with the usage of Python and Discord.py. However when I try to launch my bot I get this error in line 14: "TypeError: Client.event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'".

Here is my full code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

with open("word_blacklist.txt") as file:
    blacklist_words = [blacklist_word.strip().lower() for blacklist_word in file.readlines()]

@Bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    message_content = message.content.strip().lower()
    if any(blacklist_word in message for blacklist_word in blacklist_words):
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, "{} watch your language!".format(message.author.mention))
        await bot.delete_message(message)

@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
    Channel = client.get_channel(MY_CHANNEL_ID_1)
    Text = "Text1"
    Emoji = await Channel.send(text)
    await Emoji.add_reaction('✅')
@Bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    Channel = client.get_channel(MY_CHANNEL_ID_1)
    if reaction.message.channel.id != Channel.id:
        return
    if reaction.emoji == '✅':
        Role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Role Name")
        await user.add_roles(Role)

@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
    Channel = client.get_channel(MY_CHANNEL_ID_2)
    Text = "Text2"
    Emoji = await Channel.send(text)
    await Emoji.add_reaction('')
@Bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    Channel = client.get_channel(MY_CHANNEL_ID_2)
    if reaction.message.channel.id != Channel.id:
        return
    if reaction.emoji == '':
        Role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Role Name 2")
        await user.add_roles(Role)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I did try looking up here and in various tutorials, however I am still quite new with Python and Discord.

Answer (score 1):

You must instantiate the `Bot` class before calling stuff on it. So I would modify the code like this:

```py
client = Bot()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    message_content = message.content.strip().lower()
    if any(blacklist_word in message for blacklist_word in blacklist_words):
        await bot.send_message(
            message.channel,
            "{} watch your language!".format(message.author.mention),
        )
        await bot.delete_message(message)
```

And replace the occurrence of `Bot` and `bot` at your discretion with `client` (as I noticed your code had referred to an undefined variable `client`)